# Past simple V/s Past Perfect - was already left and had already left.

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

Can we imagine from my below examples that when we reached the platform train was not on the platform?

a) When we reached the platform train was already left / gone.

b) When we reached the platform train had already left / gone.

Answer (score 1):

a) When we reached the platform, the train was already gone.

b) When we reached the platform, the train had already left.

> In both cases above, after we have arrived at the platform, we discovered that the train has already left.

In other words, the train had already left but we didn't know this until we arrived on the platform. It is the order of events that is key here.

Order of events from both a) and b):

The Train left -> We arrived at platform -> Discovered train had already left

Comment: This is correct, but it might help the OP more if you explained *why* this is the case...

Comment: Thanks for the answer....But does it mean the same that when we reached the Station train was not on the platform.